# How many lags do I use for a VEC model with 4 endogenous variables for Residual Analysis?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model

I have 4 endogenous variables with 120 observations each. I would want to test for Autocorrelation using Portmanteau Test and LM-Type Test, for ARCH Effects using Multivariate ARCH LM Test, and for normality.

Comment: Your title does not seem to match the content. Also, your logic seems reversed; residuals should not be of primary interest. Once you have built a model (which is of primary interest), you can carry out residuals analysis.